# application commands in .net 6

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET 6 and minimal `program.cs` and I want to write a command for some of my custom logic and put it contab for example.

This is my command I wrote as a test:

```
using CommandDotNet;

namespace new_stack.Commands;

public class HelloCommand
{
    [Command("hello", Description = "Greetings command")]
    public void Greet([Operand(Description = "Name of the person")] string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that you have to register command for using it for example `dotnet Hello --john` o something like this in application
and this is I found for registering in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HelloCommand>();

var app = builder.Build();
var appRunner = new AppRunner(builder.Services);
appRunner.RegisterCommands<HelloCommand>();
```

Now I get these errors in my IDE:

> Argument type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Type'

> Cannot resolve symbol 'RegisterCommands'

I found various ways for create and register command in totally different ways and I'm confused. I'm new to .NET and I used to code PHP and I had no problems like this in symfony or laravel

Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe you should read the getting started guide: https://commanddotnet.bilal-fazlani.com/gettingstarted/getting-started-0/